# ejabberdctl command "create_room" not known

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I wanted to setup a simple jabber server to enable chat with my team. Everything went smoothly until the point I wanted to create conference rooms.

When I run ejabberdctl with no parameters, the option create_room does not appear in the list, and if I run **ejabberdctl create_room test** I get the following response:

> Error: command "create_room" not known.

My config file (/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg) is as following:

```
%% Admins of this server are also admins of MUC service:
{access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.

%% All users are allowed to use MUC service:
{access, muc, [{allow, all}]}. 

{mod_muc,      [
          %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
          {access, all},
          {access_create, all}, 
          {access_persistent, all},
          {access_admin, muc_admin},
          {max_users, 500}
         ]},
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `mod_muc_admin: []` to your `ejabberd.yml` file. You don't need `mod_admin_extra` (but if you wanted that, you'd need to enable it in `ejabberd.yml` as well). These modules are now included with ejabberd and don't need installing separately.

This worked for me on 15.06.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mod_admin_extra.

As an addition, you will also need to manually install and compil that module if you run ejabberd version before 15.04.

Comment: After 15.04 you may need to enable it in the config file with: `mod_admin_extra: []`

Comment: Hi, am using MongooseIM - i have the mod_admin_extra enabled, but i still see the same error. Is there something i might be missing?

Comment: You need to use ejabberd. Ejabberd has much more features so you will be better off switching to that version  instead of that fork.