# MongooseIM create_room command not known

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am a new comer to MongooseIM. 
I have setup the server and am able to exchange messages between two users.
Now I am trying to setup the server to enable MUCs.

I have enabled mod_muc in ejabberd.conf file. 
On executing the create_room command, the error says :

```
mongooseimctl create_room test

command “create_room” not known
```

Is there something that i may be missing.
I looked up [ejabberdctl command "create_room" not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074605/ejabberdctl-command-create-room-not-known) , but the solution there didnt work out. Is there something that is specific to MongooseIM?

Enabled modules :

```
%%%.   =======
%%%'   MODULES

%%
%% Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
%% For list of possible modules options, check documentation.
%%
{modules,
 [
  {mod_admin_extra, [{submods, [node, accounts, sessions, vcard,
                                roster, last, private, stanza, stats]}]},
  {mod_adhoc, []},
  {mod_disco, []},
  {mod_last, []},
  {mod_stream_management, [
                           % default 100
                           % size of a buffer of unacked messages
                           % {buffer_max, 100}

                           % default 1 - server sends the ack request after each stanza
                           % {ack_freq, 1}

                           % default: 600 seconds
                           % {resume_timeout, 600}
                          ]},
  {mod_muc, [
             {host, "muc.@HOST@"},
             {access, all},
             {access_create, all}
            ]},
  {mod_muc_log,
        [
        {outdir, "/tmp/muclogs"},
        {access_log, muc}
        ]},
  {mod_offline, [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
  {mod_privacy, []},
  {mod_private, []},
% {mod_private, [{backend, mnesia}]},
% {mod_private, [{backend, odbc}]},
  {mod_register, [
                  %%
                  %% Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
                  %%
                  %%{password_strength, 32},

                  %%
                  %% After successful registration, the user receives
                  %% a message with this subject and body.
                  %%
                  {welcome_message, {""}},

                  %%
                  %% When a user registers, send a notification to
                  %% these XMPP accounts.
                  %%
                  %{registration_watchers, ["admin@localhost"]},

                  %%
                  %% Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
                  %%
                  {ip_access, [
                               {allow, "0.0.0.0/0"}]},

                  %%
                  %% Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
                  %%
                  %%{access_from, deny},

                  {access, register}
                 ]},
  {mod_roster, []},
  {mod_sic, []},
  {mod_vcard, [%{matches, 1},
%{search, true},
%{host, directory.@HOST@}
]},
```

UPDATE : Moved to ejabberd. Modules enabled in ejabberd :

```
%%%   =======
%%%   MODULES

%%
%% Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
%%
{modules,
 [
  {mod_adhoc,    []},
  {mod_announce, [{access, announce}]}, % requires mod_adhoc
  {mod_caps,     []},
  {mod_configure,[]}, % requires mod_adhoc
  {mod_admin_extra, []},
  {mod_disco,    []},
  %%{mod_echo,   [{host, "echo.localhost"}]},
  {mod_irc,      []},
  %% NOTE that mod_http_fileserver must also be enabled in the
  %% "request_handlers" clause of the "ejabberd_http" listener
  %% configuration (see the "LISTENING PORTS" section above).
  %%{mod_http_fileserver, [
  %%                       {docroot, "/var/www"},
  %%                       {accesslog, "/var/log/ejabberd/access.log"}
  %%                      ]},
  {mod_last,     []},
  {mod_muc,      [
                  %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
                  {access, muc},
                  {access_create, muc},
                  {access_persistent, muc},
                  {access_admin, muc_admin},
                  {max_users, 500}
                 ]},
  %%{mod_muc_log,[]},
  {mod_offline,  [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
  {mod_privacy,  []},
  {mod_private,  []},
  {mod_proxy65,  [
                  {access, local},
                  {shaper, c2s_shaper}
                 ]},
  {mod_pubsub,   [ % requires mod_caps
                  {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},
                  {pep_sendlast_offline, false},
                  {last_item_cache, false},
                  %%{plugins, ["default", "pep"]}
                  {plugins, ["flat", "hometree", "pep"]}  % pep requires mod_caps
                 ]},
  {mod_register, [
                  %%
                  %% After successful registration, the user receives
                  %% a message with this subject and body.
                  %%
                  {welcome_message, {"Welcome!",
                                     "Welcome to a Jabber service powered by Debian. "
                                     "For information about Jabber visit "
                                     "http://www.jabber.org"}},
                  %% Replace it with 'none' if you don't want to send such message:
                  %%{welcome_message, none},

                  %%
                  %% When a user registers, send a notification to
                  %% these Jabber accounts.
                  %%
                  %%{registration_watchers, ["admin1@example.org"]},

                  {access, register}
                 ]},
  {mod_roster,   []},
  %%{mod_service_log,[]},
  %%{mod_shared_roster,[]},
  {mod_stats,    []},
  {mod_time,     []},
  {mod_vcard,    []},
  {mod_version,  []}
 ]}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the link you reference, I think you have to use ejabberd to benefit from that API (and many more).

Comment: I am now using ejabberd. 
Mod_muc and mod_admin_extra : [] are enabled. 
I still dont see create_room option in ejabberdctl.
Updated post with modules enabled in ejabberd

Comment: Thanks! I built ejabberd from source and enabled mod_muc_admin too and now able to create rooms. :)

Answer (score 0):

For creating rooms you need to use REST API, please see official documentation -https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/REST-API. Also pay attention to the Swagger Doc at the end of this page